# Change colour/theme of sharepoint 2013 mysite across the enterprise

Tags: 2013, my-site, theme

I was wondering how I change the MySite theme from the default blue/white look to the Oslo look, or one of the other default themes?

Answer (score 1):

As Moontear says you need a feature stapler for My Site.

In my last project I had a project in Visual Studio only for stapling with a Feature and an Empty Module

This is the Elements.xml of the StaplingModule

```
<!-- Custom Master This is for Branding MySite-->
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="63816940-bea4-4686-86f6-79f40eaab434" TemplateName="SPSPERS#2" />

<!-- Lists Instances -->
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="4008c0da-0127-4386-94e2-9ee8740d2420" TemplateName="SPSPERS#2" />

<!-- SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (Necessary so that Create Custom List appears in _layouts/addanapp.aspx. I needed to create Custom lists in mysite) -->
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa" TemplateName="SPSPERS#2" />
```

Now in the feature (I called it FeatureStaplingMySite) you need to make reference to the Elements.xml of the Module

```
<Feature Id="FEATURE-GUID" Scope="WebApplication" Description="$Resources:Intranet, Feature_MySite_Stapling_Description;" AlwaysForceInstall="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
      <ElementManifest Location="StaplingMySite\Elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Besides, I have another VS Project to customize mySite with a feature that activates my custom master. You can add an event receiver on that feature to activate the oslo.master for example with this code

```
public class FeatureMySiteMasterEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        if (properties != null)
        {
            SPSite sitio = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
            SPWeb web = sitio.RootWeb;
            try
            {
                ActivateMaster(web, "oslo.master", false);
                ActivateMaster(web, "oslo.master", true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Error treatment
            }                
        }
    }

    public static void ActivateMaster(SPWeb webContext, string masterPath, bool masterAdmin)
    {
        try
        {
            webContext.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            if (!rutaMaster.Contains("/_catalogs/masterpage/"))
            {
                rutaMaster = SPUtility.ConcatUrls("/_catalogs/masterpage/", rutaMaster);
            }
            Uri uriMaster = new Uri(SPUtility.ConcatUrls(webContext.Url, rutaMaster));
            if (masterAdmin)
            {
                if (!webContext.MasterUrl.Contains(masterPath))
                {
                    webContext.AllProperties["OldMasterUrl"] = webContext.MasterUrl;
                }
                try
                {
                    webContext.MasterUrl = uriMaster.AbsolutePath;
                    webContext.Update();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Error treatment
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!webContext.CustomMasterUrl.Contains(masterPath))
                {
                    webContext.AllProperties["OldMasterUrl"] = webContext.CustomMasterUrl;
                }
                try
                {
                    webContext.CustomMasterUrl = uriMaster.AbsolutePath;
                    webContext.Update();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Error treatment
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error Treatment
        }
        finally
        {
            webContext.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either have a feature stapler for your my sites, like explained here:

- [Customizing MOSS 2007 My Sites within the enterprise](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184%7D&pID=794)

If you want to change the theme for existing MySites you could do it by code like so:

```
ThmxTheme oTheme = ThmxTheme.Open(siteCollection,"_catalogs/theme/<nameoftheme>.thmx");
oTheme.ApplyTo(oWeb, false);
oWeb.Update();
```